# A step in the proof of Paley-Wiener theorem in Stein-Shakarchi

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

We are assuming the following:
\begin{equation}
|f( x + i y)| \leq A e^{2 \pi M |y|}
\end{equation}
and that $f$ is of moderate decrease on $\mathbb{R}$, meaning $f$ is continuous and satisfies $|f(x)| \leq \frac{A}{1 + x^2}$.

In step 2, we define the following function
\begin{equation}
f_\epsilon (z) = \frac{f(z)}{(1 + i \epsilon z)^2},
\end{equation}
where we take $\epsilon > 0$.

I'm stuck on the line:

But for each fixed $\epsilon$, we have
\begin{equation}
|f_\epsilon (x + i y)| \leq A'' \frac{e^{2 \pi M |y|}}{1 + x^2},
\end{equation}
which I'm stuck on because I'm getting, from the definition of $f_\epsilon$ and the first bound above:
\begin{equation}
|f_\epsilon (x + i y)| \leq A \frac{e^{2 \pi M |y|}}{(1 - \epsilon y)^2 + \epsilon^2 x^2},
\end{equation}
and I can't find a way to reproduce the equation above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh I think I get it now. We actually only need the equation true for the lower half-plane ($y \leq 0$), since we are trying to use step 1. While the bound seems to be required to hold for all $y$ in step 1, we actually just need it to hold for the lower half-plane.

Then, for $\xi < - M$, we get another bound from using their suggested factor $\frac{1}{(1 - i \epsilon z)^2}$.

Comment: $|1+i \epsilon z| \ge 1-|\epsilon y|$ therefore $A''= \frac{1}{(1-|\epsilon y|)^2}$

Comment: $A''$ should be a constant, in this case, I think it suffices to take $A'' = \frac{A}{\epsilon^2}$.